# Doxygen won't find headers in subdir

Tags: c++, header, doxygen

I'm documenting a C++ library's header files with Doxygen. In the `Doxyfile`, I defined

```
INPUT = include/
```

in the hopes that Doxygen would then generate documentation for all the header files in `include/Foo`, but it doesn't: only the `index.html` is generated. I can set `INPUT` to `include/Foo`, but then the documentation lists the headers with their basenames (`Reader.hh`), while I want clients to include the headers as `Foo/Reader.hh` etc.

How can I get Doxygen to look within the subdirectory?

Answer (score 33):

Have you set RECURSIVE to YES?

```
# The RECURSIVE tag can be used to turn specify whether or not subdirectories
# should be searched for input files as well. Possible values are YES and NO.
# If left blank NO is used.

RECURSIVE              = YES
```

it's in the `Doxyfile` (here line 608, might be sligthly different for you)

Comment: Done, but it still produces basenames for headers.